# H2O Steam integration with Apache Knox

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak, h2o, apache-knox

How do I integrate Apache Knox or Keycloak with H2O Steam to authenticate users?
In the H2O Security Model (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/security.html#), I could not find anything related to custom authentication.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider editing your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2):

No specific Knox integration exists today, but you can contact sales@h2o.ai for information about the Enterprise version of Steam.

It has significant security integration for Kerberos, LDAP, Active Directory, SSL and Hadoop proxy user impersonation, so people get their own dedicated H2O jobs running as themselves with their personal HDFS-enforced authorized data access capabilities.

Comment: With kerberos and Hadoop trusted proxy support (proxy user impersonation) an Apache Knox integration is just a matter of a service definition. 2 XML files: service.xml and rewrite.xml. Using Knox as a proxy will allow you to leverage any of the existing authentication and federation providers - including the use of KnoxSSO for enterprise SSO integrations.

Comment: Perhaps the trusted proxy support is for H20 talking to Hadoop components but not trusted proxies like Knox or Oozie talking to H20?